# Blender cycles with alpha texture and glass shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to set a nice material for the leaves.

This is my node setup:

[image]

And this is the problem (just 10 samples):

[image]
Leaves are simply planes generated by sapling plugin, and the texture is a leaf with alpha channel.
On top you can see green dots around the invisible plane.

Any suggestions?

Blender 2.69

Comment: First I'd try swapping the glass node for a translucent. The other thing I would try is to put the transparent mix before the diffuse/glass mix.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that this is caused by the alpha mask not being completely transparent, which results in the *Alpha* channel being a mix of white and dark grey instead of black. This will result in a mix of a lot of transparent shader and a tiny amount of glass/diffuse, giving the green haze.

As a quick workaround you can add a *Math* node set to `.5` with *Greater than* as the operation.
This sets all pixels above `.5` (gray) to `1` (white) and all those below `.5` to `0` (black).
Add this to the alpha channel before the mix node (click for full size):

[image: node setup image]

Without the math node:

[image]

With the math node:

[image]

Comment: I love the effects and I have different uses for your nodes. Thank you very much.